# How to stop my header scrolling down in my entire website page

Tags: html

I'm editing a downloaded version of website template. I just want to ask if someone can help me to find a way to stop scrolling that header down all my website page. My header code is the following:

```
    <header class="main_menu_area">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logosofto.png" alt="" width="250" height="240"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><font size="+1">Home</font></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html"><font size="+1">About Us</font></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="service.html"><font size="+1">Services</font></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html"><font size="+1">Portfolio</font></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown submenu">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <font size="+1">Blog</font>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="single-blog.html">Blog Details</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html"><font size="+1">Contact</font></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Can you provide further files you use (CSS?, JS?)?

Comment: Kindly make sure you have pasted full code. Try to add in the css for the header

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume you are using the bootstrap framework. Does your nav tag contain navbar-fixed or something similar.

```
<nav class=“navbar-fixed”>
```